# combining two objects for the mouseout handler of hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of headers and paragraphs as below. I would like to show the paragraph for a particular header when a user places their mouse over the header.

```
<h2>Header 1</h2>
<p>some text</p>
<h2>Header 2</h2>
<p>some text</p>
```

I am able to achieve this with jquery as follows:

```
$("h2").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
});
```

The problem is, when one mouses over the paragraph after it has been revealed, it disappears. Is there any way the mouseout event could fire only when one removes the mouse either from the header or the paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check this live [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFd4Y/4/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="section-1">
    <h2>Header 1</h2>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div id="section-2">
    <h2>Header 2</h2>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
p{
  display:none;  
}
```

#### JQuery

```
$("div").hover(function(e) {
  $("p", this).slideDown();
}, function(e) {
  $("p", this).slideUp();
});
```

Old JQuery Code only for reference:

```
$("h2").on("hover",function(e) {
  if(e.type == "mouseenter") {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
  }
  else if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
  } 
});
```

Comment: This still causes the OP's problem that when you hover over one of the `<p>`s it hides it

Comment: You want to use the "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events, and skip the "hover" event altogether.

Comment: @Josef The second paragraph still keeps sticking out after slideDown.

Comment: I could, but I'm not sure if the OP can.. ;)

Comment: thank you @JosefOttosson your work really superb. i need your permission to update my code like your jsfiddle.

Comment: Go ahead @user1153551, it's a comment on your answer and a derivative of your original fiddle, so that was my intention anyway.

Comment: the wrapper div is okay, this looks great, thank you, problem is if I have more elements in the list and mouse down the list (in the actual site I have more text in paragraphs as well) it seems that a strange animation begins when several of the divs can be sliding up and down simultaneously, this looks really unprofessional, would there be any way to prevent this from happening? thank you!

Comment: @dreamwalker You could delay one of the animations with [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/), but to create a better experience I think adjusting the element heights or changing what triggers the animation might be better.